# Hook for custom price in Woocommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am currently developing a webshop where i needed to do a separate price function. So far, with the help of woocommerce hooks, i had managed to manipulate the price in both the shopping cart and the checkout, this works without any problems at all. Hooks i have used `woocommerce_cart_item_price`, `woocommerce_cart_item_subtotals`,  `woocommerce_cart_subtotal` and `woocommerce_cart_total`.

Now we come to my problem that i need to solve in the very near future. The price from my custom function is not included in the woocommerce order. So, is there a hook to manipulate the product prices in the order before the woocommerce creates the order?

I have looked at https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html
but with no success.

Where does Woocommerce get the price from when it creates the order? The _price meta field, `woocommerce_get_price` hook, the cart or something else. I would be very grateful if someone could explain this to me. I find that woocommerce is not very consistent with where it's getting the price from.

Please ask questions if you don't understand my problem or my relative poor English. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've use the `woocommerce_get_price` hook, when you change it, that changed price will be used for the cart to calculate the total (price * qty).

After order is placed, WooCommerce calculates the product based price on the total and qty, if you change one of the 2 values (total or qty) it will change the product price.

In other words, the price is dynamic after order has been created.

**Edit:**

Added method to change price

```
function change_price( $cart ) {

    //  Exit function if price is changed at backend
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ) {
        $item['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
    }
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_price', 10, 1);
```

Comment: So first, thank you for taking som time to think on my problem.

Comment: I cannot use `woocommerce_get_price`, and the reason is that my custom price function needs cart related data to calculate the final price. In other words I have parameters in the cart that have to be passed trough some hook to my function, so I can count on them as well.

Comment: I develop a profile shop where customers can upload their logo and choose 1 color, 2 color 3 color... and so on. I store the customer's choice in the cart together with the product. Then I hook up my price function to these hooks `woocommerce_cart_item_price`, `woocommerce_cart_item_subtotals`, `woocommerce_cart_subtotal` and `woocommerce_cart_total`. Also note that via these hooks I get access to the shopping cart data.

So how do I manage to manipulate the final price in the Woocommerce orders?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain you how you can change price, it works on WC 3.0, not before

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it was the ultimate solution for my case.

Comment: Thank you. This answer - saved tons of time!

Comment: upvot the answer ;)

Comment: please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality